# Change content in element

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to remove and replace some content inbetween an a tag (`<a>here</a>`).
I unfortunately cant just change it in the HTML files. I need to change it with Jquery or PHP in Wordpress.

It gets more complicated with the fact it doesnt have any classes or ID's. The only unique feature it has is a "Data-category-slug". For example:

```
<a href="#" data-category-slug="muubs-accessories">Accessories</a>
```

In this example I need to change 'Accessories' inbetween the a tag into the word 'Muubs'. There are also several of these with different 'data-category-slug's after this one each with no classes or ID's (each needs to be changed in the same way but with different words using different "data-category-slug's") so using specificity of parent elements is out of the question unfortunately.

Any help would be great

Comment: You need to use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('a[data-category-slug="muubs-accessories"]').text('content replaced');
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify 'content' is Muubs in this example and 'replaced' is Accessories or is it the other way around?

Comment: No! "content replaced" is text that will be placed instead of "Accessories"